# Is it possible to write an alias or function in Bash to filter out the errors (stderr)?

Tags: grep, pipe, stderr

I sometimes would do

```
grep -ri foo .
```

but in some node_modules, it could have some links to places that don't exist.  So I can do a

```
grep -ri foo . 2>&-
```

or

```
grep -ri foo . 2> /dev/null
```

but sometimes it is difficult to remember.  Is it possible to write an alias so that

```
grep -ri foo . | discarderr
```

can work? I think it might be difficult to do because only the stdout is passed to `discarderr`. There probably is no way to pass both stderr and stdout to `discarderr` and have `discarderr` discard the error, such as

```
alias discarderr='cat 2> /dev/null'
```

Is there any way to do it, or maybe by a function but it probably looks a bit awkward if it is something like `discarderr(grep -ri foo .)`?

It seems grep has a `-s` that can silence the error message. But what about a general solution for other commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shell function that executes a command given as one or several arguments and discards its standard error stream:

```sh
discarderr () {
    "$@" 2>/dev/null
}
```

An alias that does the same:

```sh
alias discarderr='2>/dev/null'
```

Both would be used in the same way:

```
discarderr some-command
```

... although this is arguably obfuscating the command and more cumbersome than just adding `2>/dev/null` to a command, in the long run.  You would, for example, have to remember to instantiate the alias or function on each and every system you use, and if you use the function in a script, it hides the fact that you are discarding diagnostic messages from someone that skims the code.

Additionally, diagnostic messages are *useful*, and you should ideally correct things like dead symbolic links etc. rather than working around the fact that they causes errors in programs that tries to access data through them.

Also note that using `discarderr` would make it harder to debug "strange" issues.  You can't, for example, see whether a command was executed *at all* as e.g. `discarderr grap` (`grep` misspelled) would not output anything.

Comment: thank you. so `"$@"` means the whole command in a Bash function, and `2>/dev/null` can be placed at the very front of a command

Comment: @nonopolarity `"$@"` means "all command line arguments, individually quoted" (in any POSIX shell), and yes, redirections can be placed anywhere on the command line, for example in the front of a command.

Comment: all the arguments... and argument #1 now becomes the command... I see. thanks.

Comment: "should ideally correct things like dead symbolic links etc"... the node_modules were created using `create-react-app`, which currently is `npx create-react-app my-app`... it was installing 300MB of node_modules and today it is 260MB... so I am not too sure about what happened in node_modules (which I don't touch directly)